# What is my login and password for Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

I am lost!  Trying to login to Area 51.  I have no idea what my username should be or what the password should be using your Stack Exchange?
Can you tell me?

Answer (score 4):

Use the same login you're using here on Meta Stack Exchange. In your case, that's a Google account, so click the "log in with Google" button on Area 51:

[image]

Having said that, I don't see an Area 51 account on your profile already... and your account here on MSE seems to be pretty new. If you think you have an existing account on Area 51, give [account recovery](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) a try. If that *also* doesn't help, [drop us a line](/contact) with all the relevant details* and we'll see what's what.

---

* Do you already have an Area 51 account? Did you follow any proposals? Are you trying to create a new account? Etc. etc. Just describe the overall situation as best you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Area 51 account to be associated with your other Stack Exchange accounts, then you should log in with the "Stack Exchange" option, and use the same username and password that you used for your other accounts at [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2F#log-in).

[image: Screenshot of the login page.]

If you don't care about associating your accounts, you can create a new account by signing up with your email and a new password on [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2F#create-account).

[image: Screenshot of the signup page.]

Comment: Credential matching is the way to go, but not everyone has an email/password combo that we manage. Whether someone does or not is not something you'd know without employee/developer access, of course. But just FYI - "use the same credentials you use to log in here" is usually a safer bit of advice than "the same username/password" in the general case. (This post's pretty vague on details to begin with either way, though. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯)

Comment: Fair enough, @AdamLear. I did my best to answer the question as it was asked (OP asked for help logging in "using your Stack Exchange"), but yeah, it probably would have been more useful if I provided more general advice. Your answer is much better than mine in that regard, +1.

Comment: To be clear, nothing wrong with your answer. :) I'm just adding some perspective/guidance for future reference.