# Find my username and password for a Stack Overflow account

Tags: feature-request, openid, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid, my-logins

I know this might have been asked before. But here the scenario is somewhat different. So please read the question.

I am a little bit confused with the thing about Stack Overflow.

I created my Stack Exchange account by using my Google ID. But still, I don't know the username and password for my Stack Overflow account. I am able to log in with the Google account.

So tried to log in with my email id (the same id of my Google id), but it shows that the id does not exist. How can I get my username and password of my stock account?

Still, I am able to log in with the Google account with the stack.
I searched this issue, and I got below result, but it is not solving my issue.

1. *[What is my login and password for Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296989/what-is-my-login-and-password-for-area-51)*
2. *[Can't login with Stack Exchange username and password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217544/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-username-and-password)*
3. *[OpenID and Stack Exchange password for same email address and same account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185956/openid-and-stack-exchange-password-for-same-email-address-and-same-account)*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I created my stack account by using my google id

Great. So that's how you login.

> But still i don't know the username and password for my stack account

You don't have any. Because you use Google to login.

> How can i get my username and password of my stack account

You don't need them, because you login with google.

Comment: means i don't want to use any username and password dedicatly for stack overflow. I should use open id  ?

Comment: You are already using OpenId, with Google.

Comment: Ohh thanks @Oded i am little bit confused about this . Thanks.

Comment: You can choose to use an open Id provider (like google, facebook or any other provider) to login. Or you can create a Stack Exchange username/password to login with as well. You don't *need* a Stack Exchange username/password if you already have an OpenId login like google or facebook.

Comment: @PranavMS think of OpenID as a bridge between Google and Stack Exchange, a bridge where your credentials pass between one to the other. It's only one way.

Comment: I need a username/password and don't want to login via google.